# Dealiing with instance in class when parameters changed - Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm learning how to program and handle Python classes and have found this problem.

I have this files (example.py) and inside this file I'm importing two classes.

**example.py**

```
..
   from class_folder.automobile import Class_Automobile
   from class_folder.catalog import Class_Catalog

   class_automobile = Class_Automobile()
   class_catalog = Class_Catalog()
..
```

Inside **automobile.py** have this code:

```
from pdo_mysql import Pdo_Mysql

class Class_Automobile(object):
    """
        Description
    """
    __pdo_mysql_intern = None

    def __init__(self):
        self.__pdo_mysql_intern = Pdo_Mysql('host', 'user', 'password', 'db')
    ## End def init

    def Validate_Make(self, make_search):
      query_make = 'make_text = %s '
      result  = self.__pdo_mysql_intern.select('make', query_make, 'id_make', make=make_search)
      return result
    ## End function Validate Make
```

And inside the **catalog.py** file has this information:

```
from pdo_mysql import Pdo_Mysql

class Class_Catalog(object):
    """
        Description
    """
    __pdo_mysql_intern = None

    def __init__(self):
        self.__pdo_mysql_intern = Pdo_Mysql('host', 'user', 'password', 'db2')
    ## End def init
```

And finally the **pdo_mysql.py** file has this:

```
    import MySQLdb, sys

    class Pdo_Mysql(object):
        """
            Description
        """

        __instance   = None
        __host       = None
        __user       = None
        __password   = None
        __database   = None
        __session    = None
        __connection = None


        def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
            if not cls.__instance:
                cls.__instance = super(Pdo_Mysql, cls).__new__(cls,*args,**kwargs)
            return cls.__instance
        ## End __new__

        def __init__(self, host='localhost', user='root', password='', database=''):
            self.__host     = host
            self.__user     = user
            self.__password = password
            self.__database = database
        ## __init__

       def _open(self):
          try:
            cnx = MySQLdb.connect(self.__host, self.__user, self.__password, self.__database)
            self.__connection = cnx
            self.__session    = cnx.cursor()
          except MySQLdb.Error as e:
            print "Error %d: %s" % (e.args[0],e.args[1])
       ## End function open

      def _close(self):
        self.__session.close()
        self.__connection.close()
      ## End function close

      def select(self, table, where=None, *args, **kwargs):
         result = None
         query = 'SELECT '
         keys = args
         values = tuple(kwargs.values())
         l = len(keys) - 1

         for i, key in enumerate(keys):
            query += "`"+key+"`"
            if i < l:
                query += ","
         ## End for keys

         query += 'FROM %s' % table

         if where:
            query += " WHERE %s" % where
         ## End if where

        self._open()
        self.__session.execute(query, values)
        result = [item[0] for item in self.__session.fetchall()]
        self._close()
        return result
      ## End function select
```

When I run the example.py I have this problem, somehow when I call this

```
validate_information = class_automobile.Validate_Make(make)
```

I obtain this response

```
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 205, in execute
    self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
    raise errorclass, errorvalue
_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1146, "Table 'db2.make' doesn't exist")
```

This problem it is because the db from **Class_Catalog** is mixing when I'm calling the **Class_Automobile.**
It is solved when I put the **Class_Catalog** before the **Class_Automobile** but I want to know how to solve properlly.

---

**Update:**

Thanks to Adam Smith found the problem. I just had to change this file pdo_mysql.py:

```
class Pdo_Mysql(object):
    # all your existing definitions

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        **if not cls.__instance or not cls.__database:**
            cls.__instance = super(Pdo_Mysql, cls).__new__(cls,*args,**kwargs)
        return cls.__instance
```

Comment: 1). can you post code to the function `Validate_Make()` as well in the `Class_Automobile()`? 2). What is the argument `make` that you are passing into that function? 3). Does that parameter cover `db2` database as well?

Comment: I think this could use a new title that more accurately describes the issue (which in this case seems to have something to do with how to correctly use the singleton pattern).

Comment: My suggestion: drop all that pile of code and rewrite from scratch following proper python idioms and [coding standards](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). There are so many things that don't make sense that I really don't want to waste my time pointing all them out, to finally discover which bug is it that it creates the problems.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what's happening. When you call `class_automobile = Class_Automobile()` a new `Class_Automobile` instance is created and the `__init__` method is called on that instance. Inside `__init__` you're calling `Pdo_Mysql('host', 'user', 'password', 'db')`. `Pdo_Mysql.__new__` is invoked with Pdo_Mysql as the cls variable and `('host', 'user', 'password', 'db')` as the `args` variable. Because this is the first time a `Pdo_Mysql` object has been requested the class variable `__instance` is `None` so your `super` call is run and the result is set on the `Pdo_Mysql.__instance` variable. This is a class level assignment. You then return this instance. If you look at the [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__) you'll see that :

> If `__new__()` returns an instance of cls, then the new instance’s `__init__()` method will be invoked

So now you've got the instance of `Pdo_Mysql` from the `super __new__` call and you return it. The `__init__` method will be called on it with the `args and kwargs` sent to `__new__`. In `__init__` you set the various connection attributes.

All is fine at this point. If you were to make calls to your `class_automobile` instance they would work as you expected. Let's look at what happens when you make your next object, the instance of `Class_Catalog`.

It begins in the same way as `Class_Automobile` until we get to the `self. __pdo_mysql_intern = Pdo_Mysql` call. This time when `Pdo_Mysql.__new__` is invoked the `cls.__instance` variable is set to an instance of `Pdo_Mysql` so you don't make a new one. BUT you still return this instance from `__new__` so the `__init__` method is still run on this instance but with new `args and kwargs`. The instance variables are set to the new values. So now the instances `class_automobile` and `class_catalog` have a `__pdo_mysql_intern` variable pointing to the same instance and that instance has __host, __user, __password, and __database set to whatever the last arguments were used to initialize an instance.

Now on to one possible solution...

It appears you're trying to do some kind of connection sharing so you don't open a new connection for each object that connects to a database. However you're only allowing one instance of `Pdo_Mysql` to ever exist. This means you cannot connect to more than one database and only as a single user.

You need a pool of connections (`Pdo_Mysql` objects) to choose from so that when you want to connect to another db or as a different user you can do so. In your `Pdo_Mysql` class you could change the `__instance = None` variable to `__instances = {}`. Use the `args` as the key to this dictionary and change the `__new__` method to look up the instance using the `args`. Note that this ignores the kwargs, I leave it to you to figure out how to include them (hint, you cannot use mutable objects as keys in dictionaries). You'll also want to add a `__initialized` variable to the `Pdo_Mysql` class. Default it to `False` and set it to `True` in `__init__`. This was you can make sure you only run `__init__` on each instance once.

Going a step further I would suggest you not use `__new__` to create singletons but instead create a helper method in pdo_mysql.py called `get_conenction` or something. Have it take the same 4 arguments and it can check it's pool of instances for any that match and either return an existing connection or make a new one.

Comment: Perfect, and far better than my half-hearted answer!